# Erlang erlIDE: what are the -compile options supported?

Tags: eclipse, compiler-construction, erlang

I've been trying to get erlIDE to work with -compile options e.g.

> -compile('S').  % Generate 'assembler' listing

to no avail.  What I am doing wrong?

NOTE: I have also tried setting 'project specific' options for the compiler with no success.

EDIT: could it be that 'erlc' is invoked and forced to generate a 'beam' and thus disregards orders to generate 'assembler' output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is badly supported, currently, sorry about that. With recent releases of erlide, the .S files are created in the workspace directory instead of project/ebin. This is caused by the fact that the compiler uses the current directory, ignoring the outdir option, in this case.

regards,
Vlad